# unable to connect to mysql in joomla in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, joomla

I installed lampp in ubuntu and instaled joomla on it
and import database in phpmyadmin
when run joomla in localhost, links are inactive !
pls help me

I am sorry for bad English.

Comment: can please explain more? what are the errors you get?

Comment: Actually, I have no errors. Default page is the only pages which works but no links don't work properly.I'd be grateful if you give me a hand with that. Am I enough clear?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your question, you are probably having a problem with the links not working, due to the SEF URLs being enabled.

Without more information, there's little we can do to help you, but you should definitely check what SEO options you have in your Global Configuration, and try to make sure that there is a .htaccess file in your Joomla root directory.